# Cannot find module in node server.js

Tags: html

I am new to node server.js, so in my server.js I have an error which say

```
 Error: Cannot find module './routes/routegameconsoletype'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
   at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\joyyy\Documents\website\server.js:6:30)
   at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

However in my code, I included the `./routes/routegameconsoletype` . I have included my code below

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const routegameconsoletype = require('./routes/routegameconsoletype');
const routegameinformation = require('./routes/routegameinformation');
const routegamereview = require('./routes/routegamereview');
const routenews = require('./routes/routenews');
const routeuser = require('./routes/routesuser');
const routevideos = require('./routes/routevideos');

var app = express();
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 8080;
var startPage = "index.html";

app.use(express.static("./public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

routegameconsoletype.routegameconsoletype(app);
routegameinformation.routegameinformation(app);
routegamereview.routegamereview(app);
routenews.routenews(app);
routeuser.routeuser(app);
routevideos.routevideos(app);

function gotoIndex(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params);
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + startPage);
 }

app.get("/" + startPage, gotoIndex);

app.route("/");

var server = app.listen(port, host, function() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port);
});
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're probably not using the right directory to the file `routegameconsoletype`. Can you tell us where is this file located **with respect to** the `server.js` file?

Comment: @NayeemulIslamSwad the `routegameconsoletype` is located in `project\routes\routegameconsoletype`.

Comment: - Is your `server.js` file located in `project\server.js`?
- Does the file `routegameconsoletype` has the extension `.js`? Even if your code is requiring `routegameconsoletype`, the server actually looks for `routegameconsoletype.js`.

Comment: the `server.js` file is located in `project` . The file `routegameconsoletype` has an extension .js behind. So what i need to do is add a .js behind the `./route/routegameconsoletype.js` ?

Comment: @NayeemulIslamSwad when a `ctrl + click` on `./route/routegameconsoletye` it will lead to the file

Comment: Do you need to point to `project/route/routegameconsoletype` or to `project/routes/routegameconsoletype`? There is a discrepancy between your code posted above and your comments; that may be the cause of the error; your calls to `require` are made to `./routes/fileName...`

Comment: i am sorry i had a typo and it needs to point to `project/routes/routegameconsoletype`